# BIRT: Weird behaviour of parseInt

Tags: javascript, report, birt

I am using a report parameter in BIRT.

It a string, which contains the month/year, like: 08/2018

To test the value, I am using the following code. It is located in a Dynamic Text:

```
var dateStringArray = params["monthYear"].value.split("/");
var date = new Date(parseInt(dateStringArray[1]), parseInt(dateStringArray[0]) - 1, 1);
var t = parseInt(dateStringArray[0]);
t;
```

If I fill the parameter with 08/2018, I get a NaN, see:

[image: Result of parseInt("08")]

But if I fill the parameter with 07/2018, it is working correctly:

[image: Working correctly]

I have tested it with several numbers. It is just not working with 08 and 09. All other number til 10 are working...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a weird scenario. Need to raise a bug on this.
But for your workaround, you can make use of the code below in Dynamic Text which is working fine:

```
var dateStringArray = params["monthYear"].value.split("/");
var monNum;
if (BirtStr.charLength(dateStringArray[0]) == 2) 
{monNum = BirtStr.right(dateStringArray[0],1);}
else {monNum = dateStringArray[0];}
monNum;
//var date = new Date(parseInt(dateStringArray[1]), parseInt(dateStringArray[0]) - 1, 1);
var t = parseInt(monNum);
t;
```

Comment: Can I get an information about the javasxript version, which is used in BIRT?

Comment: I am using BIRT version 4.8
`BirtStr.charLength()` and `BirtStr.right()` are in-built BIRT functions

Comment: Can you test it on your side? Because I am using BIRT 4.8, too.

Comment: Sorry, i just meant, if you test to parse the string 08 or 09 to an int

Comment: Yes using the code which I have given, we can parse 08 and 09 to an int.